Conditions for network stability
Apart from poles lying in the left half of the \$s\$-plane, there is one more condition for stability:
If the transfer function is \$H(s) = N(s)/D(s)\$ then degree of \$N(s)\$ should be less than that of \$D(s)\$.
But if the degree of \$N(s)\$ is greater than that of \$D(s)\$, by long division, \$H(s)\$ be written as
$$H(s) = k_m s^m + k_{m-1} s^{m-1} + \dots + k_1 s + k_0 + \frac{R(s)}{D(s)}$$
Intuitively this makes sense but I'm not able to prove it using Inverse Laplace transform. Considering only the polynomial terms of \$H(s)\$, they contribute only impulse functions and its derivatives in the time domain, which are highly localized and don't have an effect as \$t\to\infty\$. As per my understanding, only the rational term \$R(s)/D(s)\$ decides the stability as  \$t\to\infty\$. Please help me understand this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
